# How to ignore org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException in Elasticsearch log

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having a user-generated input field that translates to a simple query string query in Elasticsearch. The code is picking up any invalid input in that field and presenting it for the user. But every time a user inputs something that is invalid, an exception is logged in the Elasticsearch log file like this:

```
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException: Cannot parse 'INVALID LIKE THIS: \");': Lexical error at line 1, column 94.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "\");"
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase.parse(QueryParserBase.java:114) ~[lucene-queryparser-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0 9060ac689c270b02143f375de0348b7f626adebc - jpountz - 2018-06-18 16:52:15]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.search.QueryStringQueryParser.parse(QueryStringQueryParser.java:793) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryStringQueryBuilder.doToQuery(QueryStringQueryBuilder.java:1042) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    ... 21 more
```

This is expected since this is an invalid query. My question is, is it possible to ignore these exceptions being logged. Since the user can write anything here, I don't want invalid queries to fill up my log since this is expected.

Disclamer: I know that this is a bit dangerous. Having free-text input is not preferred. And if I disable this exception, I will also miss if I make a mistake in the query generation or similar.

Comment: Are you calling the `query` function in your code or is it being called by a dependent library?

Comment: It's a query using `query_string` but call from C# through the NEST library.